# How do I resolve `ld: library not found for -lm` when compiling with gfortran?

Tags: macos, fortran, homebrew, gfortran

I recently updated to MacOS Monterey. When I try compiling any fortran program using `gfortran`, I get the following error message:

```
ld: library not found for -lm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I resolve this? I tried

```
brew reinstall gcc
brew reinstall gfortran
```

without being able to resolve the issue. All of these programs previously compiled without issue.

Comment: Maybe this thread may give you some hints: https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/New-macOS-Big-Sur-return-quot-ld-library-not-found-for-lSystem/m-p/1228071

Comment: `alias gfortran="gfortran -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib"` in .zshrc as they suggest doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you install m?

Comment: @RichardBarber No. What is m? How do I install it?

Comment: @user2 Did you ever solve this problem? I'm getting the same terminal output when trying to run a case for a piece of software. I can't for the life of my figure out what to do about it. I have limited familiarity with running programs through the command line and zero with Fortran. FYI I'm using Big Sur.

Comment: @n_bandit: See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem after upgrading to Monterey. Turns out XCode had not be (re)installed. Run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to install **Xcode.app** in app store，then install **Xcode CTL** and finally install **gcc**.

(Re)installed these may help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).